# Where is the light sensor on iMac 27' 2020?

Tags: imac, hardware, screen

Where is the ambient light sensor on iMac 27' 2020? I'd like to put a webcam cover without affecting the sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 mm to left of webcam on my 2019 iMac - I think yours is the same.  Look carefully and you should see a 1 mm grey circle.  But a finger over it and (with auto-brightness enabled) the screen will dim a bit.

You should still be able to cover just the webcam.

Comment: Can you verify if there is a 1mm grey circle to the RIGHT of the webcam on the 2019 iMac? I put my webcam cover to the right and think I may have missed it! My vision is poor... I ask because there is a second 1mm grey circle to the RIGHT on my 2013 iMac. thanks

Comment: @John Yes, there is a 1mm grey circle to the Right of the web cam. It is very hard to see.  When the web cam is enabled, this is the spot which glows with a green light.